# Why does initializing static field cause dreaded runtime "Ambiguous match found"?

Tags: c#, static, runtime

The following declaration causes the error:

```
private static IDictionary<int, string> Dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

While the following does not:

```
private static IDictionary<int, string> Dic;
```

What the...? I know I can initialize the dictionary in a static constructor, but what I really want to use is a literal initializer (same problem).

**Edit**: It appears the issue is related to the static constructor. If I declare a static constructor, I get the same error. No doubt by initializing the field, the compiler generates a default static constructor. Parts of our app use reflection to select a class to instantiate -- I think it may be getting confused by the static constructor method.

In fact, I can add any static field (`static int i = 0;`) with an initializer and get the same results. This actually has something to do with the architecture of our whole app. I am going another way with this. Thanks for all your input.

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with all the references I have. It's in a big project.

Comment: Have you imported a namespace that contains a `Dictionary<,>` type (other than the one in `System.Collections.Generic`)?

Comment: look at http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2006/08/11/Ambiguous-match-found.aspx and http://dotnetdebug.net/2006/03/21/ambiguous-match-found-in-a-web-control-a-possible-bug/

Comment: @Ani, but if I change the declaration to `private static Dictionary...` I get the same results. Why does it only care if I initialize it?

Comment: To sum things up, while this code is correct compiler-wise (two parameters with the same characters but different casing are two different parameters), the implementation that tries to access some of it uses a case insensitive reflection search, which causes the bug.

Until I get more information from Microsoft, I suggest making sure in any ASP.NET application that is precompiled to avoid having the same names with different casing to variables in the ASPX/ASCX page and its code behind. `FROM THE REFERENCED PAGE IN PREVIOUS COMMENT`

Comment: So change the name of `Dic` to sth else long enough to preventing the same err

Comment: @Jani: I can change the name of the field to any random string and get the same results.

Comment: @Ishmael but the problem caused by naming the properties or fields , read the referenced page and follow the steps that he did and catch the exception details.

Comment: Dictionary is ambiguous, IDictionary is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya8yx9sc.aspx) to create instances of our presentation classes. The binding flags included a flag that turned on searching for static constructors. Removing this flag eliminated the error. As I said in the question, it seems initializing a static field will cause the compiler to generate a static construtor.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an ambiguous reference, it's because there's more than one type within your `using` namespaces that has that name, so the compiler doesn't know which one you're referring to. You can make it explicit like this:

```
private static IDictionary<int, string> Dic = 
    new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Comment: Or, to make it an even more absolute type identifier: global::System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>, though I don't really think that's necessary. :)

Comment: @ShdNx: True, though that would only solve the issue if the type in question was `SomeOtherNamespace.System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` ;)

Comment: If that were the case, I think the dev compiler would complain. This is thrown by the runtime. Anyway, no help.